# Insert image into html code variable

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP variable like this:

**Example1**

```
$data = '<p>This is paragraph.</p>
         <p title="not-special">No!</p>
        ';
```

**Example2**

```
$data = '<p>This is paragraph.</p>
         <p title="special">Yes!</p>
        ';
```

I want to have a php function, that checks whether there's p element with title="special", and if so, insert div element "YAP!".

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish it in various different ways, a working one could be:

```
    $data = '<p>This is paragraph.</p>
<p title="special">Yes!</p>
';
if (strpos($data, 'special') !== false) {
    $data = '<p>This is paragraph.</p>
    <p title="special">Yes!</p>
    <div>YEP</div>
    ';
}   
echo $data;
```

Anyway, this was not the best way to ask a question, please have a look at: [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is there a way to replace, for instance "<p title="special">Yes!</p>" with "<div class="replaced"></div>"?

Comment: Anyway, in my example you can simply modify the new generated $data variable as you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a special case for formatting in a view, you can specify it easily with a variable.

```
<?php
// Check somewhere for the special case
$specialCase = $_GET['success'];
?>

<p>This is paragraph.</p>
<p title="special">Yes!</p>

<?php
// Display the extra div.
if ($specialCase === 'true') {
    echo '<div class="yap"></div>';
}
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP Function to check if the variable contains a certain string, see: http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php

Comment: And how would I insert <div> into that specific position?

Comment: See the answer of giacomo pittalis!